# Transformar Coluna em linha "Pivot"

Tags: sql

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou tentando transformar a coluna "prtnum" grifada de amarelo em Linha, estou tentando usar o PIVOT mas não estou conseguindo já tentei de algumas formas e não da certo:

```
Select 

 Distinct (ORD_LINE.ordnum),
 ORD_LINE.prtnum,
 Sum (ORD_LINE.ordqty)

From ORD_LINE


Where 
ORD_LINE.entdte >= trunc (sysdate, 'MM')

Group By ORD_LINE.ordnum,ORD_LINE.prtnum
```

Comment: Está utilizando Oracle correto?

Comment: Isso mesmo amigo

Comment: O Pivot no Oracle tem de informar TODAS as possíveis ocorrências , não sei se neste caso seria viável        pivot 
(
   Sum (ORD_LINE.ordqty)
   for state_code in ('7131410','7196660'...)
)